# writing a function to return an array of a "column" from a Json Obj

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to return the values from this array using a function.
The desired result in this case is 4, 3, 22. Located in the second column of selection1

```
var list = 
{"selection1": [

{"answers": [1, 4, 5, 7]}, 
{"answers": [4, 3, 2, 1]},
{"answers": [10, 22, 12, 34]}, 

],

"selection2": [

{"answers": [31, 34, 35, 37]}, 
{"answers": [44, 43, 42, 41]},
{"answers": [20, 42, 22, 54]}, 

]};
```

and I want to return a desired column by calling

```
get_column_from_object(1, list, 'selection1') to return [4, 3, 22]
```

How do I write a function that allows me to return these values from my array?

This is where I got too

```js
var list = {
  "selection1": [{
    "answers": [1, 4, 5, 7]
  }, {
    "answers": [4, 3, 2, 1]
  }, {
    "answers": [10, 22, 12, 34]
  }, ]
};

function get_column_from_object(column_number, array, property) {
  var answer = [];
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    answer.push(array[i][property].answers[column_number]);

  }
  return answer;
}
var new_array = get_column_from_object(1, list, 'selection1');

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new_array;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have quotes around `selection1` in the call?

Comment: maybe but I'm asking for help - at the moment there is no function written. I'm asking how I write a function... to select these values

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? How to iterate over an array, how to access an object key from a variable?

Comment: If you can't even write the example properly (you don't know the difference between variables and strings), you need to study the language more.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property for how to access the property dynamically.

Comment: Hi Barmar, I've tried to explain myself better now

Comment: It should be `object[i][array].answers[column_number]`

Comment: There's no need to fill the array first. Use `answer.push()` instead of assigning to `answer[i]`.

Comment: Your parameter names are very confusing. `object` is an array, not an object. `array` is a property name, not an array.

Comment: Apologies for the incorrect terms - I thought my array (as you described) was a JSON object. Shall I edit the post to make these terms less confusing. Thanks for your help already.

Comment: Editing would be good.

Comment: edited: tried to use all correct terms. Thanks again for your help getting this question written correctly.

Comment: That code looks like it should work.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GG6FDDBW51KZ

Maybe I'm missing quotations, I tried a few options

Comment: Like I said earlier, you need quotes around `selection1`: `get_column_from_object(1, list, 'selection1')`

Comment: Otherwise it uses it as a variable, which doesn't work because you never assigned it.

Comment: apologies, edited but still no result. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GG6FMQAFF7AW
I'll continue to look into it.

Comment: I misread your object, I thought it was an array. See https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GG6KX0SJVOSS

Comment: Thanks Barmar, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Barmar for the solution

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var list = {"selection1": [{"answers": [1, 4, 5, 7]}, {"answers": [4, 3, 2, 1]},{"answers": [10, 22, 12, 34]}, ]};

function get_column_from_object(column_number, object, property) {
  var answer = [];
  var array = object[property];
   for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
     answer.push(array[i].answers[column_number]);

     }
  return answer;
}


var new_array = get_column_from_object(1, list, 'selection1');
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = new_array;

</script>
```